# How to calculate float confidence interval in Stata?

Tags: stata, confidence-interval

When estimating the risk ratio of a variable with multiple categories, I did not see many using floating confidence interval which is an absolute scale, instead, people are used to the conventional confidence interval, which is a relative scale. How can I calculate float confidence interval in Stata? Thanks!

Comment: The following paper discusses floating confidence intervals, conventional confidence intervals and how to calculate them in Stata with the user-written program `ftocci`. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0169260709002958; Nicola Orsini, From floated to conventional confidence intervals for the relative risks based on published dose–response data, Computer Methods and Programs in Biomedicine, Volume 98, Issue 1, 2010, Pages 90-93, https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cmpb.2009.11.005.

Comment: @Cybernike Thank you. But I'm interested in calculating floating confidence interval,  rather than conventional confidence interval...

Comment: What sort of regression model are you using?

Comment: I‘m using cox regression model